# Is it accurate to say reverse repo is 'conflicting' with monetary policy?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, money-supply, federal-reserve

As seen in the chart, historically, reverse repo levels have been fairly small or at most, a few hundred billion dollars:

[image]

Now into the USD trillion handle, it's a more prominent fixture of the money market. Some back-of-the-envelope arithmetic: with repo rate (at time of writing) at 1.55%, the counter parties of the fed are getting ~USD100million every day. I'm not sure how this compares with inflation if we annualize or quartirize each series, but it seems quite attractive.

### Question

Granted that policy rates affect more than just the money market, but insofar as a higher repo rate and larger reverse repo volume are mechanically bloating the amount of money the Fed injects into the system, can we accurately say this is counteracting the Fed's monetary tightening stance (rate hikes/shrink balance sheet rhetoric/QT rhetoric)? Would be interesting to look at some ratios or formulae to assess the net effect.

**Note:** Again, would like to focus on money market but if answers wish to address the wider picture, I won't object.